# can't kill installer made with innosetup

Tags: windows-7, powershell, installer, kill

For years I have been making installers with innosetup, on Windows XP SP3.
I have just installed the latest innosetup, 5.5.6 (u) (for Unicode) on Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit. I made a new installer, successfully, but when I run it, nothing is displayed, then I see 3 instances of the installer in the task manager.

I try to End Process, no effect. I have tried pskill and it reports success in killing the process, but it is still there. Then I tried the PowerShell 4 program "kill" (or "spps") with -Force and -Id . Some instances would die, others persisted.

Strangely, when I run the installer, the User Access Control challenge does not appear.

I have also run installers made months ago with innosetup, with similar results.

Do you know if some recent Windows Update has broken things?

Thanks, Jim

Comment: I think you’ll get better help if you [file a bug report](http://www.jrsoftware.org/contact.php) with Jordan Russell.

Comment: The obvious solution is to try the non-Unicode version and see if the problem is unique to the Unicode version or not.  If it is then you the most obvious solution, is determine the language pack that would be required, and change it to the language pack you have installed since Windows 7 Professional provides a limitation on the language packs installed.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The people on the InnoSetup forum were very helpful.

Comment: I found it was the DeepScreen component of Avast Internet Security that was trapping the program. I turned that off, and the installer now works properly as it used to. Avast's DeepScreen used to handle this installer properly. I'll see if Avast have a fix in the works.